# Using Go for getting the current operations of Mongo for versions less than 5 is not working

Tags: mongodb, go

As the title says,when using currentop command for mongodb version 3 or 4 is not giving me any results in inprog.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rkJX.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITq7s.png)

```
var currentOpsResult CurrentOpsOutput
        err := client.Database("admin").RunCommand(context.TODO(), bson.D{{"currentOp", 1}}).Decode(&currentOpsResult)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error executing aggregate command:", err)
            return nil, nil
        }



type CurrentOpsOutput struct {
    Inprog []FirstBatchItem `json:"inprog"`
}

type FirstBatchItem struct {
    Active            bool            `json:"active"`
    Client            string          `json:"client"`
    ClientMetadata    ClientMetadata  `json:"clientMetadata"`
    ConnectionID      int             `json:"connectionId"`
    CurrentOpTime     time.Time       `json:"currentOpTime"`
    Op                string          `json:"op"`
    Type              string          `json:"type"`
    Microsecs_running int             `json:"microsecs_running"`
    Desc              string          `json:"desc"`
    AppName           string          `json:"appName"`
    Host              string          `json:"host"`
    Secs_running      int             `json:"secs_running"`
    NS                string          `json:"ns"`
    EffectiveUsers    []EffectiveUser `json:"effectiveUsers"`
    RunBy             []EffectiveUser `json:"runBy"`
}
```

But if I run this for versions above 5, it works and there are results in inprog.

Also for the same database, I tested in Java and compass they do have results.

Any idea why this might be.

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easy for people to help you. Also, adding the expected output sure would help.